# Where is Tarrey Town?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Was listening to the OST of BotW, and found the theme of Tarrey Town.

Dont think I've ever seen that town? Where is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, Tarrey Town is a town *you* build as part of a chain of side quests. [This article](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2017/03/guide_how_to_unlock_tarrey_town_zelda_breath_of_the_wilds_amazing_hidden_gem) explains how to go about building Tarrey Town:

> To start the Tarrey Town quest you first have to save a house in Hateno Village from demolition at the hands of the Bolson Construction Company. You can find the house right next to the Myahm Agana Shrine, across a small bridge just behind some new homes that have been erected by the construction company.
>
> Head to the rear of the property and you'll encounter the flamboyant Bolson himself, boss of the construction firm which carries his name. He explains that the house in question is being pulled down at the behest of the village people, but that he can let you have it for 30 bundles of wood and 3000 Rupees.

Once you've paid Bolson, you can start the quest to build Tarrey Town by doing the following:

> To trigger the "From the Ground Up" quest which eventually leads to the construction of Tarrey Town, talk to Bolson's co-worker, Hudson, who should be found right outside your home. He informs you that he's off to make a start on Bolson's next big project, and promptly leaves for the Akkala region.

Once you've complete this quest, you will be able to take on numerous side quests to improve Tarrey Town.

For reference, Tarrey Town can be found here on the map:

> [image: tarrey town on map]

[(image source)](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/zelda-breath-wild-building-tarrey-town-guide/)

Comment: Although your link mentions it, you should also answer the question *Where is Tarrey Town?* in your answer.

Comment: @ian_itor done.

Comment: Now your answer deserves a +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

You build up Tarrey Town in the quest "From the Ground Up." [The quest](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/From_the_Ground_Up):

> begins during the Hylian Homeowner quest, starting when Hudson leaves for Lake Akkala.

It's location is here on [the Map](http://www.ign.com/maps/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/hyrule):

[image: Tarrey Town]